# setMaximumFractionDigits is not working for ThreadLocal<NumberFormat>

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, number-formatting, thread-local

To make the NumberFormat operation threadsafe, I have used ThreadLocal as follows:

```
public class ThreadSafeNumberFormatter {
    private static final ThreadLocal<NumberFormat> numberFormatHolder = new ThreadLocal<NumberFormat>() {

        @Override
        protected NumberFormat initialValue() {                     
            return NumberFormat.getInstance();
        }
    };

    public static NumberFormat getNumberFormatter() {
        return numberFormatHolder.get();
    }
}
```

But when I am using the ThreadSafeNumberFormatter, setMaximumFractionDigits is not working:

```
NumberFormat FORMAT = ThreadSafeNumberFormatter.getNumberFormatter();
FORMAT.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
```

If i use the following instead, works fine:

```
NumberFormat FORMAT = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    FORMAT.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: NumberFormat.getInstance should be getNumberInstance I guess

Comment: It works in this example build from your code: http://ideone.com/MCYBZG  Can you post a full example that reproduces your error?

Comment: i had the code FORMAT.setMaximumFractionDigits(2); in a static block. That's where is the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are setting it in one thread and trying to read from it in another thread.  That obviously won't work.  We can't really tell without more of an example.